# Find all $x$ such that $8^x(3x+1)=4$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms, transcendental-equations

> Find all $x$ such that $8^x(3x+1)=4$,and prove that you have found all values of $x$ that satisfy this equation.

**My effort**

Rewriting the equation I have 
\begin{array}
22^{3x}(3x+1)&=2^2 \\
\log_2{2^{3x}(3x+1)} &=\log_2{2^2} \\
3x +\log_2{(3x+1)} &=2 \\
\end{array}

I don't know how to simplify from there,looking it up with Geogebra it appears clear that I have only one solution at $x=1/3$  but how can I show this from the last equations ?

If you can give me some hint ,that would be best.

Comment: It seems that both $0$ and $33$ are not solution.

Comment: This is a trancendental equation. You can either show that a numerical answer appears to converge to $1/3$, or you can solve it by inspection... Plug in $x=1/3$, and go with David's answer.

Comment: @zahbaz yeah,I see.I thought there was still some algebraic manipulation which would have led me mechanically to the answer.

Comment: I hear ya. In general, equations of form $x a^x = c$ will rely on numerical approaches. There's no way to isolate $x$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is clear that any solution must have $3x + 1 > 0$, or $x > -1/3$. For $x > -1/3$, the function $f(x) = 8^x (3x + 1)$ is increasing, hence the equation $f(x) = 4$ has at most one solution. But $x = 1/3$ is a solution, so it is the only one.

Comment: Danke.So it was just a matter of making accurated guesses about the solution.

Comment: To find $x$, yes. But to prove that there were no other possibilities, it took an additional argument.

Answer (score 1):

You ended up with the system $\log (1+a)=2-a$ where $a=3x$. Observe that $2-a$ is strictly decreasing and $\log (1+a)$ is strictly increasing function of $a$. So there is a unique solution thanks to intermediate value theorem.